# How many bytes does character takes if I created database with utf8 in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-5.7

Suppose if create a database with utf8 character set and created table and inserted data. 
Here my doubt is if the character is 1 byte then  it will occupy only 1 byte or it will occupy 3 bytes because of utf8 character set

Answer (score 3):

Depends on a character. Some need one byte, some - four. See http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm .
MySQL has two UFT8 character sets:

```
mysql> SHOW CHARACTER SET like 'UTF8%';
+---------+---------------+--------------------+--------+
| Charset | Description   | Default collation  | Maxlen |
+---------+---------------+--------------------+--------+
| utf8    | UTF-8 Unicode | utf8_general_ci    |      3 |
| utf8mb4 | UTF-8 Unicode | utf8mb4_general_ci |      4 |
+---------+---------------+--------------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

If a character is a one byte, it will use one byte in memory and on a disk. If four - then four. Plus the string will use one or two bytes to encode length of the string.
Note, that `utf8` character set cannot encode all UTF8 characters.

Answer (score 2):

`CHAR(n)` -- Depending on the vintage of your copy of MySQL and the `ROW_FORMAT`, `CHAR` may allocate a full 3 bytes per character.

`VARCHAR(n)` -- This will occupy one or two bytes for a length, plus only as many bytes are needed.  That is each character will occupy 1, 2, or 3 bytes for the `CHARACTER SET utf8` (utf8mb3).

In general, you should go for `utf8mb4`, with a max of 4 bytes per character.

After you have inserted some text, do

```
SELECT col,
       HEX(col),
       LENGTH(col),      -- number of bytes
       CHAR_LENGTH(col)  -- number of characters
    FROM ... WHERE ...;
```

This should let you see for yourself what is going on.

Answer (score -1):

From [MySql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html):

> Requires a maximum of four bytes per multibyte character.

Or, if your database character encoding is set as utf8mb3:

> Requires a maximum of three bytes per multibyte character.

So, yes, an utf8 character will occupy the same size in your database as it would have. No more, no less.